# No option to "run as" a Local C/C++ Application when using STM32CubeIDE

Tags: c, stm32cubeide

I am trying to follow a Udemy course to learn Embedded C programming but I have come across a problem. When being asked to run what I am working on, the course says there should be an option to "Run As" a "Local C/C++ Application, but I don't have this option and I don't seem to be able to find it anywhere. The image below shows what I should be seeing,

[image: Local C/C++ Application]

But below is what I actually see,

[image: Actually what I see]

I have installed MinGW 64 bit as you can see from the next screenshot,

[image]

How do I make the "Local C/C++ Application" "Run As" option visible in STM32CubeIDE?

Comment: How did you create the project? How did the course create the project? If you created an `STM32Cube` project I think you might not have that option.

Comment: STM32CubeIDE has turned down default support for building to the local target (PC). Probably, this option existed in earlier versions but not anymore. You may try to download e.g. STM32CubeIDE version 1.0.2.

Comment: I have reverted back and the option is now there, thanks for your comment. I am going to test it a bit more to make sure it is working correctly and then I will add this as the answer. Thanks again

Comment: You try to use the wrong tool. This IDE is designed for STM micros and using for anything else makes no sense. Older version were very buggy, so do not downgrade, rather install Eclipse CDT this was designed for building PC programs. Use the correct tool

Comment: Thanks but the course I am taking is teaching me how to use an STM chip, it uses an STM32F4-Discovery board (i.e. the Embedded part of the course title). I think the early stages are just to show you the basics of programming in C, that is why he is using this IDE to build on the PC. Although I have got it to work by downgrading, the lecturer has said he is using version 1.7.0 so there must be a way of getting this option available in the latest version.

Comment: I have managed to add a "Run As" option that uses the Local C/C++ Application, it just looks different from how it does in the lectures as he is using the old version. I will answer the question and show what mine looks like just in case anyone else searches for this.